# Getting a key and value from nested Hashmap

Tags: java, network-programming, hashmap, switching, openflow

So, I'm creating a nested hash map for two switches using the switches ID and then putting in a source Mac address and a port.

E.g. switch1 should contain its own mappings, as should switch2 and both switches should obviously communicate with each other, so I've set the HashMap up like so:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Long, Short>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Long,Short>>();

if(sw.getId() == 1){
        switchMap.put("1", new HashMap<Long, Short>());
        switchMap.get("1").put(sourceMac, (short) pi.getInPort());
}
else if(sw.getId() == 2){
        switchMap.put("2", new HashMap<Long, Short>());
        switchMap.get("2").put(sourceMac, (short) pi.getInPort());
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is check each switch's key (either 1 or 2) and then check that each switch has the correct sourceMac and port# when checking a given destinationMac:

```
Long destinationMac = Ethernet.toLong(match.getDataLayerDestination());

if (switchMap.containsKey("1") && switchMap.containsValue(destinationMac)) {    
    /* Now we can retrieve the port number. This will be the port that we need to send the
    packet over to reach the host to which that MAC address belongs. */
    short destinationPort = (short) switchMap.get("1").get(destinationMac);
    /*Write the packet to a port, use the destination port we have just found.*/
    installFlowMod(sw, pi, match, destinationPort, 50, 100, cntx);
} 
else if (switchMap.containsKey("2") && switchMap.containsValue(destinationMac)) {   
    /* Now we can retrieve the port number. This will be the port that we need to send the
    packet over to reach the host to which that MAC address belongs. */
    short destinationPort = (short) switchMap.get("2").get(destinationMac)
    /*Write the packet to a port, use the destination port we have just found.*/
    installFlowMod(sw, pi, match, destinationPort, 50, 100, cntx);
}
else {
    log.debug("Destination MAC address unknown: flooding");
    writePacketToPort(sw, pi, OFPort.OFPP_FLOOD.getValue(), cntx);
}
```

When I run the code and try to ping from h1(switch1) to h3(switch2) I get requests back, but I still get the error message `"Destination MAC address unknown: flooding"`

My question is, am I getting the values from the nested HashMap correctly? Or is my logic completely messed up?

Comment: I've seen you've edited your question, but as far as I understood it doesn't invalidate my answer. The problem you're facing is just in how you're retrieving the data from the switchMap. You are trying to retrieve the value of `destinationMac` from switchMap, instead you should retrieve it from the inner map associate to one of the 2 switches as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(String s: map.keySet()){
    HashMap<Long, Short> switchMap =map.get(s);
    if(switchMap.containsValue(destinationMac)){ 
        return switchMap.get(destinationMac);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're checking the presence of the destination address is wrong. It should be something like:

```
Short portS1 = switchMap.get("1").get(destinationMac)
if (portS1 != null) {
  installFlowMod(sw, pi, match, portS1, 50, 100, cntx);
}

Short portS2 = switchMap.get("1").get(destinationMac)
if (portS2 != null) {
  installFlowMod(sw, pi, match, portS2, 50, 100, cntx);
}
```

For this to work you have to initialize all your switch mapping with an empty `Map<Long, Short>`.

An even more generic approach would be this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Long, Short>> e: switchMap.entrySet()) {
  Short port = e.getValue().get(destinationMac);
  if (port != null) installFlowMod(sw, pi, match, port, 50, 100, cntx); 
}
```

Doing it this way you do not even need to pre-initialize the switchMap.

Comment: I've tried both solutions, but I keep on getting a null pointer exception. My debug log only shows switch1 connecting, then disconnecting, then reconnecting again. The switches do need a connection to each other as well as their separate hosts

Comment: I'd suggest to edit your question in order to mention the Exception you're getting, otherwise it's difficult for readers to try and help you as we do not have the necessary context. Finally remember that we do not know the inner working of your algorithms. The answer you've got are limited to the lookup in the inner map. If you're now facing a different problem it would be better to close this question and to open a different one focused on your current issue.